# Android: Softkeyboard along with main application

Tags: android

I want to create a custom keyboard with handwriting capabilities that is intended to be used with one of my application, I am creating a keyboard using InputMethodService API, I am wondering whether it is possible to package this custom keyboard along with my main application, or should I submit the soft keyboard and my application separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can package it with your application.  Unless you're doing some special processing that's really integral to your app I wouldn't suggest this though.  Handwriting isn't a popular way of text entry outside of Asia, and there are existing apps with years to decades of research into handwriting analysis.  Unless you've bought a 3rd party library from one of them you're unlikely to be in the same league.

Comment: For handwriting integration, I am using some third party library

Comment: Ok, then the answer is yes.  Just add the appropriate permissions when you declare the service in the manifest.